# Cross-compiling: Error adding symbols: File in wrong format collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cross-compiling, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Cross-compiling c++ test application for aarch64 compiler and linking boost library using Cmake files. I keep getting this error that the format of the boost library is not correct. Here is my CMakeList and the error im getting.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.10.2")


project(testapp2)

# Target operating system name.
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
# Name of C compiler.
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "aarch64-linux-gnu-g++")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-m32")
set(BOOST_ROOT "./local/boost_1_73_0") # either set it here or from the command line  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "./local/boost_1_73_0/boost")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

add_executable(testapp2 main.cpp)

install(TARGETS testapp2 DESTINATION bin)

install(FILES main.cpp DESTINATION src)

target_include_directories(testapp2 PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(testapp2 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Error:

```
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried to add the  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="m32" and it gave me this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/c++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /root/testapp2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_3dc9d/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3dc9d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3dc9d.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/root/testapp2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3dc9d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /usr/bin/c++    m32    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3dc9d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /root/testapp2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    c++: error: m32: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to be sure you built the Boost libraries using the **same** compiler (and architecture) you are using for building your CMake application. Also, your CMake points to a Boost version here `./local/boost_1_73_0/boost` but the linker is using a boost library `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so` here. Perhaps, CMake found the wrong set of Boost libraries, if you have *more than one set* on your system. Also, setting the `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and other internal CMake variable should never happen in a CMakeLists.txt file, do this in a toolchain file instead